# Computing many2one field for specific field data

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-14

Im trying to access a different data that is being displayed by the many2one field using Odoo Studio but haven't reached out the right way to do it. I cant re-code the backend since Im being hosted remotely so I'll need to use the computed field option to do so.

This is the many2one field Im currently having.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXmIa.png)

And this is the object that the many2one field is reaching out.

[Object being reached out by the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iebD.png)

But this is the actual field that I need.

[Field trying to be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vZyr.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with your issues, but are to do so there certain expectations you need to meet. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Mainly, **do not post images or links**, instead post formatted text. Additionally post the code you have tried and your actual table definitions (ddl), also as text.